# How to delete folder after the order ends

Tags: magento-1.9, php, directory

Im new in Magento, I need to delete a file and its containing folder, which has a name generated by the following code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id_order);
$increment = $order->getIncrementId();

if (!file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/Ocproveedores/'.$increment)) {
    mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/Ocproveedores/'.$increment, 0777, true); 
}

$tcpdf->Output(Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/Ocproveedores/'.$increment.'/OC-'.$nombreProveedor.'-'.$increment.'-'.$j.'.pdf', 'F');
```

How can I delete the folder after ending an order ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use `rmdir()` to delete a folder according to your exemple, I think that there is no Magento function for that !

Now if you want to do that in some condition **after ending order**, you can use an `observer` with this event `sales_order_place_after`. you can take an exemple from [this](http://blog.meetphpexperts.com/event-after-save-order-or-place-order-in-magento/) to look how to create an observer